# Can you use async programming with an update in a transaction?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

In VSCode when I add the await keyword before an update in a transaction, the word await is underlined and when I scroll over it I see the message "await has no effect on the type of this expression. ts(80007)"

Is this message correct? If so, could updates in transactions cause any synchronicity issues?

I'm not actually using TypeScript in my app, but I suppose the message still could be relevant.

In case it helps, here's the full code of the transaction. It's a poker app and the goal is to make sure that when multiple players join a table at the same time it doesn't try to add more players than allowed to the table.

```
playersNumberAfterTransaction = await firestore.runTransaction( async(t) => {
    const firstNotFullTableDocSnapshot = await t.get(firstNotFullTable.ref);
    const firstNotFullTableDocRef = firstNotFullTableDocSnapshot.ref;
    const newPlayersNumber = firstNotFullTableDocSnapshot.data().playersNumber + 1;
    if (newPlayersNumber < 9) {
      const seat = firstNotFullTableData.seatsRemaining.pop();
      player.seat = seat;
      if (!cardsData) {
        cards = await generateDeckOfCards();
        await firstNotFullTable.ref.collection('cards').doc('deck').set({
          gameCards: cards,
        })
      }
      await t.update(firstNotFullTableDocRef, {playersNumber: newPlayersNumber, seatsRemaining: firstNotFullTableData.seatsRemaining})
      await newPlayerDocRef.set(
          player
      )
      return newPlayersNumber;
    } else {
      throw 'too many players at table'
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code being referred to here.  What you have now is cut off.  It is always better to copy the text into the question itself than to take a screenshot.

Comment: I made those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a transaction, [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction#set(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference,%20java.lang.Object)) and [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction#public-transaction-update-documentreference-documentref,-mapstring,-object-data) don't return a promise.  They are synchronous and return the current transaction object.  TypeScript is reminding you of that.  The writes are queued up and executed as a batch when the transaction handler returns, so there is no need to await anything.